# What's the difference between Hitman GO and Hitman GO: Definitive Editon?

Tags: version-differences, hitman-go

In 2014, Square Enix released [*Hitman GO*](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hitman-go/id731645633), a turn-based puzzle game, on iOS and Android. Two years later, the game was re-released as [*Hitman GO: Definitive Edition*](http://store.steampowered.com/app/427820/Hitman_GO_Definitive_Edition/) on PC, PS4, and Vita.

The Steam page for *Hitman GO: Definitive Edition* doesn't list any new features or differences when compared to the original, so I'm not sure what makes this new version "definitive".

**What's the difference between *Hitman GO* and *Hitman GO: Definitive Edition*?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated on [Square Enix's blog](https://na.square-enix.com/us/blog?page=5&d=03%2F2016), posted on 2/15/2016, the only major difference between Hitman GO and Hitman GO: Definitive Edition is improved graphics.

> It’s basically the good old Hitman GO you loved on mobile, with updated visuals and all the great content we added on to it including my personal favorites, the Paris Opera from Blood Money, and the St. Petersburg Stakeout mission from Hitman 2: Silent Assassin

As the additional content on the mobile version were free updates, Square Enix more than likely made the comment towards the additional content to assure players that the content will be maintained in this version.

Comment: The Paris Opera and St. Petersburg Stakeout levels were added on iOS as free updates, so it sounds like the only difference is updated visuals.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro After doing more research, it appears the improved graphics is the only different major then. Square Enix probably added in the comment towards additional content to ensure players that it will still be there